# Correct sitting posture for my bicycle

Tags: seatpost, ergonomics

I recently bought the below bicycle 26 inch

https://www.trackandtrail.in/cycles/mach-city/ibike-7-speed/

My Height is 5:11,   after riding for one week i started feeling pain at upper back below neck and also near the shoulders,  Can you recommend correct sitting posture for this flat handle cycle.

Also can you recommend few links for good warmup exercise before cycling.

Comment: Understand that, if you suddenly start riding a bike, after not riding for years, you will be using muscles you haven't used recently.  They will get sore.  As the muscles get stronger and more used to the exercise the pain will abate.

Comment: Another problem is that most bikes these days are sold with the handlebars too low for most riders.  This is because a bike with a low handlebar looks "sexier" on the showroom floor.  Used to be, with quill stems, it was possible to raise the handlebar significantly after purchase, just by loosening a bolt, but with "threadless" headsets you need a bike shop's a$$i$tance.  (But this is more of a problem for bikes with drop handlebars.)

Comment: To be fair, lower handlebars also put you in a more aerodynamic position allowing you to go faster with less effort.  You'll often find that bikes with drops have them really low because they are designed for racing. Road race bikes and cx bikes are the main bikes you'll find with drop bars, which are primarily designed for racing. If you go for something built more for comfort like a touring or city bike, then you'll find the height difference between the handlebars and seat is much smaller.

Comment: @DanielRHicks The bike in question isn't a racing bike but a hybrid-commuter-type bike. In my experience, those tend to be sold with the handlebars slightly higher than the saddle. Also, any half-way decent bike shop should be prepared to adjust a bike it recently sold for free.

Comment: @Kibbee The bike linked in the question has flat handlebars; it's a hybrid-commuter-thing, not a race bike.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - "Slightly higher than the saddle" is still apt to be too low.  And who said anything about a halfway decent bike shop?

Comment: Another simple help is to unsnap any brim or visor that is on your helmet.  Trying to see under the visor can make you extend your neck too far.   Downside, no visor for rainy days or riding into the sunlight.

Comment: @Criggie That's the great benefit of a cap. The peak can be flipped up or down.

Comment: @David Good to see you working on the review queues. Perhaps this [resource](http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/1024/8273) will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two items to consider are bicycle fit and riding position.  Here is a link to how the position of the controls can effect neck and back pain http://bikeandbody.blogspot.com/2012/02/have-neck-and-shoulder-pain-on-bike.html  The post discussed positioning of the hoods on a drop bar bike but I am sure you can extrapolate the information to your own circumstances given your flat bar bike.

An additional thing to consider relative to fit is cockpit room... it is not just a matter of handlebar height relative to the seat.  Reach can have a huge impact on comfort particularly with the back and neck.  Too much reach has you stretched out and too little room (short reach) has you hunched over.. both situations force your head/neck into unnatural positions to see the road when riding...   Top tube length is the primary factor effecting reach but considering you already have your bike you can play on the margins by adjusting your seat fore and aft, as mentioned in the comments you can adjust your bar height, or you can get a new stem that can affect both bar height and reach.

With the proper fit, consider riding form.  Your elbows should be slightly bent... that is purposely bent... and your back slightly arched (not hunched).  this position has the effect of pulling your head and shoulders up so you can see the road without having to hold your head back.  It has the added benefit of opening up your breathing pathways.... elbows bent, back arched should be a mantra until it becomes your natural riding position.

Play with your fit.. you may want to consider getting a professional fit especially if you are considering investing in a new stem or bars.  The professional fit will inform you on what would be best considering your current setup.

good luck